# AJAX 'success' Calling before AJAX has executed in IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

### A Brief Description

Another Internet Explorer issue to add to the list... I have a button on my page that closes the current tab/window, but before doing so it executes an AJAX request to 'delete the document session'. Very simple stuff:

```
MN.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "JSON",
    errorText: 'There was a problem deleting the session, please retry later',
    success: function(data){
        // Close the tab/window
        window.open(window.location, '_self').close();
    }
});
```

***Ignore the `MN.ajax()`, this is just a wrapper function for `$.ajax()`, it works the same but with a few extra bits such as 'errorText'***

### The Issue

The above code works in every browser apart from IE. In IE, it closes the window/tab before the AJAX request has actually been executed. The AJAX request should delete a record from my database but no record is deleted unless I comment out the line `window.open(window.location, '_self').close();`

### Possible Solution

I have not tested this, but I assume that if I wrap the close window with a `setTimeout` then it should work. However, what I would like to know is why!!? Why on earth would it execute the 'success' function before the AJAX request has actually completed?

### What I have tried...

One other thing I have tried is to put the 'close window' code into the `complete` call back instead of the `success` callback, but this made absolutely no difference...

### Update

Here is the full containing function:

```
/**
 * Close the Document
 */
MN.closeDocument = closeDocument;
function closeDocument(document_reference,session_id){
    // Show the loading dialog
    MN.loadingDialog('Closing Document...',function(){
        // Execute the autosave function to save the session
        MN('#document-modify-form').autosave('save',function(){
            MN.ajax({
                url: '//api.example.net/document/session/'+document_reference+'/',
                dataType: "JSON",
                errorText: 'There was a problem getting the documents session',
                success: function(data){
                    // Only close if there are no changes
                    switch(data.status){
                        // There is no session or no changes
                        case 'no_session':
                        case 'no_changes':
                            // Delete the session
                            MN.ajax({
                                url: '//api.example.net/document/delete-session/'+document_reference+'/',
                                dataType: "JSON",
                                errorText: 'There was a problem deleting the session, please retry later',
                                success: function(data){
                                    // Close the tab/window
                                    window.open(window.location, '_self').close();
                                },
                                error: function(msg){
                                    // Error code here
                                }
                            });
                        break;
                        // Other cases here
                    }
                },
                error: function(msg){
                    // Error code here
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: How about making a synchronous call?

Comment: @RafaelDiaz That shouldn't make a difference as the function still should not be executed until the ajax request has been completed!

Comment: this is strange. Well, have u tried when then/done ? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @SyedQarib You are missing the point, fixing this is not really my aim as I could probably do that in 30 seconds with some sort of dirty fix. What I would actually like to know is why on earth it doesn't work in the first place? How can the 'success' function be called before the AJAX request has been completed?

Comment: +1 This is definitely an interesting phenomenon!  Have you however tested it with the vanilla `$.ajax` just to be certain it's nothing in your override?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Tested and also not working. My wrapper function does very little other than some clever error handling so I didn't think it would make much of a difference

Comment: Hmmm, ok, what about any other arbitrary code rather than the `window.open...` ? Wonder whether the IE JS interpreter is somehow executing the `window` scoped methods immediately as opposed to other code?  Or perhaps wrap it in another anonymous function?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker To be honest, I don't think this is an 'interesting phenomenon' as much as it is once again incapable coding from the teams at Microsoft! :-P. I think if I wrap it in a `setTimeout` then it should work...

Comment: Yes I'm inclined to agree :( However it 'should' be normalised by jQuery.  Having a setTimeout is ugly, hacky and potentially other UI interferences which would give you/users undesirables side-affects. :(

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Exactly, it is the last thing I want to use!

Comment: Are you sure you're not just seeing the page change as a result of not calling `e.preventDefault()` when clicking on a link?

Comment: @Alnitak Absolutely certain I'm afraid

Comment: Very strange, then - this absolutely shouldn't happen.  Can you put a `console.log` line at the head of the callback to show whether it's really being invoked?

Comment: @Alnitak Yes but the tab will then close so you wont see the log...

Comment: You can't "detach" the console so it survives refreshes? (I don't use MSIE much in anger, but you can do the above in Chrome).

Comment: @Alnitak I dont use IE too, if I had my way I wouldn't bother developing for it but sadly have to cater to the clients needs... If you can detach the console, I don't know how :-(

Comment: well I guess for testing purposes you could just try an `alert` instead of `console.log`

Comment: @Alnitak The alert actually worked, but the script executed at url did not get called...

Comment: weirder and weirder...   Can you please show how the above code is invoked?

Comment: @Alnitak I will try and produce a jsFiddle, may take me some time, this is an enormous application! Will get back to you in a min

Comment: I don't have MSIE available where I am now, but a small self-contained example that replicates your issue would be very interesting.

Comment: @Alnitak I have added the full containing function and stripped out everything that I know for a fact has nothing to do with the issue. You can ignore the function called loadingDialog, and please also note that I have tried this executing this outside the `closeDocument` function and this also does not work...

Comment: I wonder if your browser is somehow cacheing the result of a previous request for `/delete-session/` thereby avoiding making the new request?  In REST applications this would typically be a `POST` operation (or better yet `DELETE`)

Comment: @Alnitak I have tried setting `cache` to false and this did not work. I can change the request to POST and see if that works?

Comment: @Alnitak POST also does not work

Comment: @Alnitak I have figured out what the issue is! Will post it up as an answer in a min :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I have figured out what the issue is. There is absolutely nothing wrong with the functionality of `$.ajax` and calling `window.open(window.location, '_self').close();` within the success callback. This works!

The document session I was trying to delete was in fact being deleted, but because the window was being reopened and then closed by `window.open(window.location, '_self').close();`, the session was being recreated! So it appeared as if the session was never being deleted.

This means there are two solutions to my problem, either, do not use `window.location` as this reopens the same page, thus recreates the session, or find another way to close the tab/window using javascript.

Thanks for all your assistance, sorry to waste your time! :-)

Comment: hopefully the `alert` would have shown this - you would have had a deleted session initially, and then as soon as you dismissed the alert it would have reloaded and re-created the session.  The other factor causing confusion is that you're presumably re-using the session ID - using a new identifier would have made it obvious that you were creating new sessions over and over.

Comment: @Alnitak It is not that sort of session unfortunately. The alert would have shown it, I was just too careless to check the sessions between the two... Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Fair enough, but what led you to believe this was an MSIE-specific problem?  How did the behaviour differ from other browsers?

Comment: @Alnitak The issue didnt occur in other browsers. The session was deleted as I wanted it to be

Comment: so in reality it was the behaviour of `window.open().close()` that differed?

Comment: @Alnitak Yes. My solution was to change `window.open(window.location, '_self').close();` to `window.open('', '_self').close();`

Answer (score 0):

I've built the following simplified test page from your code. This works on my system (Win8.1 x64, IE11) as expected: the window closes after 3 seconds, when the ajax call completes.

***ajax.php:***

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
sleep(3);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ajax test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test_click()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    // Close the tab/window
                    window.open(window.location, '_self').close();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="test_click()">Close</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is the OP is trying to save something `onbeforeunload`